# Looking for syntax equivalent in cURL library

Tags: php, android, curl, paypal

Am trying to write the following 
cURL command line in a PHP script:

-d"grant_type=client_credentials"

Which CURLOPT option would be the 
most appropriate. It's for Paypal 
access-token request for my android 
app.

Answer (score 0):

It's a POST variable, so

```
$data = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Arrays are [also acceptable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), of course.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the quick response. @Sergeyvidusov